# CSS Flex - random white space at the bottom of element when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

sorry this is going potentially tricking to understand without viewing - but I've used Flex to create a responsive grid, expanding content when a tile is clicked. It behaves strangely in two ways I can't understand, firstly, when the page is loaded for the first time and the first tile is clicked, it expands but the `.active-tile` doesn't seem to get added (background green) - it works every time following that. And secondly, only on devices 961px> , again, doesn't happen on first tile clicked, but a random whitespace is created at the bottom of the `tile` element, can anyone advise as to what this might be?

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/simoncunningham/zsLxuo26/17/

any advice would be appreciated!

```
<div class="box">
      <div class="tile" onclick="openTab('b1');">
        <img src="./Icons/Banking.svg" />
        <p>Banking</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="b1" class="content" style="display: none; background: black">
        <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
          >&times;</span
        >
        <div class="description">
          <h3>Banking</h3>
          <p>
            The largest category covering investment and management platforms,
            sales and trading analysis toosl, personal finance management &
            crypto exchanges.
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Personal Finance Management (PFM)</li>
            <li>Investment Data and Information Services</li>
            <li>Trading and Investment Platforms</li>
            <li>WealthTech Operations</li>
            <li>Distributed Ledger Technologies & Cryptocurrencies</li>
            <li>Robo Advisors</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tile" onclick="openTab('b2');">
        <img src="./Icons/RegTech.svg" />
        <p>RegTech</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="b2" class="content" style="display: none; background: black">
        <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
          >&times;</span
        >
        <div class="description">
          <h3>RegTech</h3>
          <p>
            The largest category covering investment and management platforms,
            sales and trading analysis toosl, personal finance management &
            crypto exchanges.
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Personal Finance Management (PFM)</li>
            <li>Investment Data and Information Services</li>
            <li>Trading and Investment Platforms</li>
            <li>WealthTech Operations</li>
            <li>Distributed Ledger Technologies & Cryptocurrencies</li>
            <li>Robo Advisors</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tile" onclick="openTab('b3');">
        <img src="./Icons/InsurTech.svg" />
        <p>InsurTech</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="b3" class="content" style="display: none; background: black">
        <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
          >&times;</span
        >
        <div class="description">
          <h3>InsurTech</h3>
          <p>
            The largest category covering investment and management platforms,
            sales and trading analysis toosl, personal finance management &
            crypto exchanges.
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Personal Finance Management (PFM)</li>
            <li>Investment Data and Information Services</li>
            <li>Trading and Investment Platforms</li>
            <li>WealthTech Operations</li>
            <li>Distributed Ledger Technologies & Cryptocurrencies</li>
            <li>Robo Advisors</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tile" onclick="openTab('b4');">
        <img src="./Icons/Lending.svg" />
        <p>Lending</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="b4" class="content" style="display: none; background: black">
        <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
          >&times;</span
        >
        <div class="description">
          <h3>Lending</h3>
          <p>
            The largest category covering investment and management platforms,
            sales and trading analysis toosl, personal finance management &
            crypto exchanges.
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Personal Finance Management (PFM)</li>
            <li>Investment Data and Information Services</li>
            <li>Trading and Investment Platforms</li>
            <li>WealthTech Operations</li>
            <li>Distributed Ledger Technologies & Cryptocurrencies</li>
            <li>Robo Advisors</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="tile" onclick="openTab('b5');">
        <img src="./Icons/Accounting.svg" />
        <p>Accounting</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="b5" class="content" style="display: none; background: black">
        <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
          >&times;</span
        >
        <div class="description">
          <h3>Accounting</h3>
          <p>
            The largest category covering investment and management platforms,
            sales and trading analysis toosl, personal finance management &
            crypto exchanges.
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Personal Finance Management (PFM)</li>
            <li>Investment Data and Information Services</li>
            <li>Trading and Investment Platforms</li>
            <li>WealthTech Operations</li>
            <li>Distributed Ledger Technologies & Cryptocurrencies</li>
            <li>Robo Advisors</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tile" onclick="openTab('b6');">
        <img src="./Icons/Payments.svg" />
        <p>Payments</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="b6" class="content" style="display: none; background: black">
        <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
          >&times;</span
        >
        <div class="description">
          <h3>Payments</h3>
          <p>
            The largest category covering investment and management platforms,
            sales and trading analysis toosl, personal finance management &
            crypto exchanges.
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Personal Finance Management (PFM)</li>
            <li>Investment Data and Information Services</li>
            <li>Trading and Investment Platforms</li>
            <li>WealthTech Operations</li>
            <li>Distributed Ledger Technologies & Cryptocurrencies</li>
            <li>Robo Advisors</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tile" onclick="openTab('b7');">
        <img src="./Icons/Quote.svg" />
        <p>Quote</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="b7" class="content" style="display: none; background: black">
        <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
          >&times;</span
        >
        <div class="description">
          <h3>Quote</h3>
          <p>
            The largest category covering investment and management platforms,
            sales and trading analysis toosl, personal finance management &
            crypto exchanges.
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Personal Finance Management (PFM)</li>
            <li>Investment Data and Information Services</li>
            <li>Trading and Investment Platforms</li>
            <li>WealthTech Operations</li>
            <li>Distributed Ledger Technologies & Cryptocurrencies</li>
            <li>Robo Advisors</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tile" onclick="openTab('b8');">
        <img src="./Icons/WealthTech.svg" />
        <p>WealthTech</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="b8" class="content" style="display: none; background: black">
        <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
          >&times;</span
        >
        <div class="description">
          <h3>WealthTech</h3>
          <p>
            The largest category covering investment and management platforms,
            sales and trading analysis toosl, personal finance management &
            crypto exchanges.
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Personal Finance Management (PFM)</li>
            <li>Investment Data and Information Services</li>
            <li>Trading and Investment Platforms</li>
            <li>WealthTech Operations</li>
            <li>Distributed Ledger Technologies & Cryptocurrencies</li>
            <li>Robo Advisors</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.tile,
.active-tile,
.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tile {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  order: 0;
  flex-basis: 25%;

  /* For visual only  */
  background-color: #222;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active-tile {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  order: 0;
  flex-basis: 25%;

  /* For visual only  */
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: green;
  height: 125px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  order: 1;
  flex: 1 0 100%;

  /* For visual only  */
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #228b22;
}

.description {
  text-align: left;
}

.icon-spacing {
  margin-top: 24px;
}

/* Clear floats after the tiles */
.box:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.closebtn {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

/* 
  "Desktop" and above
 */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .box {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .content {
    order: 0;
  }
}
```

```
  function openTab(tabName) {
        var i, x;
        x = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          x[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = 'block';

        // Get all the tabs into a collection
        // (don't use .getElementsByClassName()!)
        let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tile');

        // Set up a click event handler on each of the tabs
        tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
          tab.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            // Loop over all the tabs and remove the active class
            tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
              tab.classList.remove('active-tile');
              tab.children[2].classList.remove('arrow-up');
            });

            // Set the background of the clicked tab
            this.classList.add('active-tile');
            tab.children[2].classList.add('arrow-up');
          });
        });
      }
```

Comment: About the white space, I edited the css of .active-tile, and removed the height: 125px, which makes the height to be 150px, same as all the other tiles.
*sorry for bad english btw, just trying to help*

Comment: Also, you start the event listener only after the first click. You should start listening to the event when the document is ready using window.onload.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: ahh Tomer you legend - that works great for the white space! ps your English is perfect! 

as for the `window.onload` - would you mind attaching the code for how that should look?

Comment: Of course! you may add this:
window.onload = function(){
    // just copying the listener initiator here:
            tabs.forEach(function (tab) { ... 
            }
}

Comment: @TomerLevitski Doh, didn't see your comment and did the answer below

Comment: np bro. BTW, you should always start your js code that affects elements only after the page has been loaded. Some users may have poor network and this may cause errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your event listener is so:

- there is one `onclick` on each tile div
- when the first one is clicked, you define new `click` listeners on all tiles
- and in the newly defined listeners, you implement the logic of assigning `active-tile` class to the required element

That way, your first click does not give `active-tile` to the needed element. Regarding your code, you'll need to pass a second argument to `openTab` from your html. `event` is builtin and works by default, e.g:

```html
<div class="tile" onclick="openTab('b1', event);"></div>
```

then in your .js:

```js
function openTab(tabName, event) {
  event.target.classList.add("active-tile");
  event.target.children[2].classList.add("arrow-up");
  // ... rest of the function body is fine
}
```

That does the job for the green background thing.

And about the little white thing under tiles, you've given a `height: 125px` to them, which is smaller that their parent (`box`). removing `height` should be fine.  the `tile` would occuppy all height available to it.

This is the edited fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/g54umqfL/3/

Comment: But a way better code, as @tomer-levitski mentioned, is to remove all `onclick`s from html, and define all event listeners in your javascript file, inside `window.onload`. That makes the code more structured, more controlled and more less buggy.